# gfortran Error: Integer too big for its kind at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I want to see integer kind number of gfortran

so I write this line

```
write(*,"(1X,I20,'correspond to kind  ',I2)"),11111111111,kind(11111111111)
```

There will be compilation error says

> precision of type test.f90:67:57: Error: Integer too big for its kind
>   at (1). Th is check can be disabled with the option -fno-range-check

So I tried recompile with `-fno-range-check`. But it gives result

> -1773790777correspond to kind   4

What is wrong? On the other hand, intel fortran gives no error and correct answer

Comment: It's a duplicate, yes. However,  Vladimir F's answer is much better than the accepted answer to the other question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An integer literal without any kind designation is always of the default kind no matter what value you enter<sup>1</sup>. There is therefore no much sense to even inquire

`kind(111111111111)`

the kind of any such literal is always the default kind, provided the value is valid. So the same as `kind(1)`.

All integer kinds have a limited range of values. The largest one you can get using

```
write(*,*) HUGE(1)
```

Here instead of `1` you can use any other constant or variable of the integer kind you examine. Most often, the default value of `HUGE` will be `2147483647` which corresponds to 32-bit integers.

To use larger integer literal constants, use larger non-default kinds.

It doesn't matter if you use the methods from Fortran 90:

```
integer, parameter :: lk = selected_int_kind(15)

write(*,*) 11111111111_lk
```

or from Fortran 2008

```
use iso_fortran_env

integer, parameter :: lk = int64

write(*,*) 11111111111_lk
```

Both will work. Of course `kind(11111111111_lk)` will return the value of `lk`.

---

<sup>1</sup> That is in standard Fortran. Some compilers may promote a large value to a larger kind for you, but only as a non-standard extension. You may be unpleasantly surprised when moving to a compiler, which keeps the standard behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir F. Very sorry for late comment. But I think "An integer literal without any kind designation is always of the default kind" is compiler dependent. Because intel fortran automatically support any integer literal without kind marks

Comment: I don't understand. Of course you can use integer literals without a kind designation, but they are of the default kind. The value of the default kind is processor dependent.

Comment: I mean for intel fortran kind(1) gives 1, kind(111) gives 2, kind(111111) gives 4 etc, But for gfortran kind(1),kind(111)，kind(111111)  all gives 4. I mean they are different, processing of integer literal is compiler dependent

Comment: You results are wrong. Kind(1) returns 4 on intel fortran too.

Comment: Oh, my god. I am sorry, I look into the wrong place. But I tried again, though kind(1) gives 4, but kind( 11111111111) will gives 8. So intel fortran automatically switches to kind=8

Comment: Yes, this is possible, it is a non-standard extension similar to the behaviour in C. In standard Fortran every literal without kind designation is of the default kind even if it is too large. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better explanation, but this is how I understand it. The short answer is the compiler defaults to a 4 byte integer.

Fortran is statically typed and you have not declared a variable type.  The compiler is forced to use the default integer kind, 4 bytes in this case. The [kind](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gfortran/KIND.html#KIND) function simply returns the 'kind' of integer used. The compiler is letting you know that you are trying to assign a value too large for a 4 byte integer.  When you apply `-fno-range-check` the compiler ignores this fact and the value overflows, thus the negative value returned.  You can specify that the default integer kind be 8 bytes, `-fdefault-integer-8`. See the gfortran [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html)

Example foo.f90:

```
program foo
    write(*,"(1X,I20,' correspond to kind  ',I2)"),111111111111,kind(111111111111)
    write(*,"(1X,I20,' correspond to kind  ',I2)"),11,kind(11)
end program foo
```

Compiled with:

```
$ gfortran -fdefault-integer-8 -o foo.exe foo.f90
$ foo
```

Results in:

> 111111111111 correspond to kind   8
>   11 correspond to kind   8

So you can see the compiler is indifferent to the actual value you are testing.

However, I don't think this gets at the root of what you are trying to do, which I assume is to discover the minimum size of integer necessary for a specific numeric value.  I don't know of a way to do this off hand with fortran.  See this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22646699/673590) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274499/673590) for solutions you might be able to port from C. The second approach looks promising. In a dynamically typed language like Python the type assignment is handled for you.

```
>>> type(111111111111)
<type 'long'>
>>> type(11111)
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: *which I assume is to discover the minimum size of integer necessary for a specific numeric value. I don't know of a way to do this off hand with fortran*  If that is indeed OP's intention then the intrinsic `selected_int_kind` provides the way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I had overlooked that one.  I think Vladimir's answer explains it well.

Comment: thank you, tharen. Your explanation is convincing.